# Can I use a custom validator for a RequestBody that is a string?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, validation

I have created a custom validator that should validate if the body of a request (a simple string) is in Json format. I see that the custom validator is never called. Here are some parts of my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> authorize(@RequestBody  @MyValidator String token) {

    // logic
    
}
```

This is the annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { JsonSyntaxValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface MyValidator {

    String message() default "{Token is not in Json syntax}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

This is the validator:

```
public class JsonSyntaxValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(JsonFormat constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    /**
     * It returns true if the Google Pay or Apple Pay token is in Json format.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String token, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        boolean isValid = true;

        try {
            JsonParser.parseString(token);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

I have tried invoking the endpoint with postman passing it a string not formatted as json and in debug I see that the check is skipped past.

I don't want to have a POJO with fields, I just want the request body as a string.
I haven't found much online, only a post stating that it might not be possible.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: I have solved the issue simply using a service which does what the custom annotation is meant to do... I don't think that I can use custom annotations on simple objects like Strings...

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be using the @Valid annotation instead of @MyValidator. I updated your controller below to what should work.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> authorize(@Valid @RequestBody String token) {

// logic
```

}